# How to write infinite loop logic in C++ which listens to specific data at every cycle?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

Say I have several parameters, and specific combinations trigger specific actions. The parameters are dynamic and will be updated during runtime. Every time I update a parameter, I except the output to change depending on what method is triggered in the loop.

Currently I am running the loop with delay `std::this_thread::sleep_for(Xs);` and maintaining a global variable that counts the number of loop cycles. I am hard-capping this number to avoid memory leaks or CPU-hogging.

But I want this loop to run infinitely, until I stop execution of the program, constantly checking dynamic variables. How is it possible?

Comment: This is quite broad a topic. Memory leaks shouldn’t happen anyway, but for events mutex or semaphore or some other signaling method would probably be useful. Depends on how many variables there are and what exactly you want to do. But even busy loop with sleep can run indefinitely without issues.

Comment: *"I am hard-capping this number [of loop cycles]"* -- which causes this loop to not run infinitely, right? So... don't do that if you want the loop to run infinitely. Is there more to your question than that?

Comment: sleeping is almost never a good idea, you probably need something like std::condition_variable/std::mutex/variable combination to wake up your thread when a value changes (or your program signals it is about to end so your thread can stop nicely).